# How to call action method using query string in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, querystringparameter

[image]

Question: when new employee created I have to send mail to the admin. right now mail sending successfully but when admin clicks the link directly it should open the created employee partial view along with partial 1 and partial view 2 for your reference please find below the image.

i dont know how to do this one. right now directly i called the action method
Example:

it should call the following action method

1. //websitename/seachcountry
2. //websitename/listofemployee
3. //websitename/emplyesearchbyid

which is the best way to call from the email link.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there already a view containing all these partial views and a single viewmodel tied to this view that has all the required info?

Comment: it depends on how you are displaying employee details. As @corix010 asked, do you have a container view with these partial views or do you have a separate employee details view, where you render just the `Partial View 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, to call an action using query string, your action should look like the following in your controller:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeInfo(string query)
{
    // use query here
}
```

However, I suggest create an employee details action and view that would correspond to route like //websitename/employee/details/id.

This view must be tied to a viewmodel that contains all required info about the employee (including the data in partial views).